# Tirar a Média da soma de duas colunas e divisão de duas colunas

Tags: r, dataframe

Desejo tirar a média da soma de 2 colunas da seguinte base:

```
> dput(head(censo3))
structure(list(UF = c("Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", "Rondônia", 
"Rondônia", "Rondônia"), Direção.dos.trabalhos.do.estabelecimento.agropecuário = c("Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente", "Produtor(a) titular diretamente", 
"Produtor(a) titular diretamente"), Grupos.de.área.total = c("Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha", 
"Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha"), Utilização.das.terras = c("Lavouras - permanentes", 
"Lavouras - permanentes", "Lavouras - temporárias", "Lavouras - temporárias", 
"Lavouras - área para cultivo de flores", "Pastagens - naturais"
), Utilização.das.terras..1. = c("Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", 
"Lavouras ", "Lavouras ", "Pastagens "), Utilização.das.terras..2. = c(" permanentes", 
" permanentes", " temporárias", " temporárias", " área para cultivo de flores", 
" naturais"), Condição.legal.do.produtor = c("Produtor individual", 
"Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)", 
"Produtor individual", "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)", 
"Produtor individual", "Produtor individual"), Nº.dos.estabelecimentos.agropecuários.com.área..Unidade. = c("29", 
"4", "46", "6", "8", "5"), Área.dos.estabelecimentos.agropecuários..hectares. = c("X", 
"X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "50", "40"), Mínimo = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0"), Máximo = c("0,1", "0,1", "0,1", "0,1", "0,1", "0,1")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 25L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Em que:
 Quando a Coluna "Área dos estabelecimentos" for igual a X, a média se dará pela soma da coluna de "Mínimo" e Máximo" /2.

Quando a Coluna "Área dos estabelecimentos" for igual a um nº, a média se dará pela divisão da coluna "Área dos estabelecimentos" por coluna "Nº dos estabelecimentos"

Como posso tirar essa média? Meu data frame tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
> str(censo3)
'data.frame':   42534 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ UF                                                      : chr  "Rondônia" "Rondônia" "Rondônia" "Rondônia" ...
 $ Direção.dos.trabalhos.do.estabelecimento.agropecuário   : chr  "Produtor(a) titular diretamente" "Produtor(a) titular diretamente" "Produtor(a) titular diretamente" "Produtor(a) titular diretamente" ...
 $ Grupos.de.área.total                                    : chr  "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha" "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha" "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha" "Mais de 0 a menos de 0,1 ha" ...
 $ Utilização.das.terras                                   : chr  "Lavouras - permanentes" "Lavouras - permanentes" "Lavouras - temporárias" "Lavouras - temporárias" ...
 $ Utilização.das.terras..1.                               : chr  "Lavouras " "Lavouras " "Lavouras " "Lavouras " ...
 $ Utilização.das.terras..2.                               : chr  " permanentes" " permanentes" " temporárias" " temporárias" ...
 $ Condição.legal.do.produtor                              : chr  "Produtor individual" "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)" "Produtor individual" "Condomínio, consórcio ou união de pessoas (inclusive casal, quando os dois forem responsáveis pela direção)" ...
 $ Nº.dos.estabelecimentos.agropecuários.com.área..Unidade.: chr  "29" "4" "46" "6" ...
 $ Área.dos.estabelecimentos.agropecuários..hectares.      : chr  "X" "X" "X" "X" ...
 $ Mínimo                                                  : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ Máximo                                                  : chr  "0,1" "0,1" "0,1" "0,1" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma maneira de fazer o que a pergunta pede, só com R base.

Primeiro fazemos uma cópia das colunas da base que vão ser processadas. E transformamos os seus vetores em vetores numéricos tendo em atenção que as casas decimais estão marcadas com vírgulas. É necessário substituí-las por pontos.

```
tmp <- censo3[(ncol(censo3) - 3):ncol(censo3)]
tmp[] <- lapply(tmp, function(x) as.numeric(sub(",", ".", x)))
```

Agora onde estavam `"X"` estão valores `NA`.
Portanto, é só usar um `ifelse` para saber quais os pares de colunas de que se vão calcular as médias.

```
media <- media <- ifelse(is.na(tmp[[2]]), rowMeans(tmp[3:4]), tmp[[2]]/tmp[[1]])
censo3$media <- media
```

Finalmente, arruma-se a casa.

```
rm(tmp, media)
```

Comment: Onde é X, também desejo calcular a média, porém, pelas soma da colunas "Máximo" e "Mínimo" dividido por 2

Comment: @IngledMCardoso Sim, é isso mesmo que o código faz.

Comment: Desculpe, quero dizer que quando a coluna "Área de estabelecimentos" é um número, está sendo calculado, porém não a média. Quando a Coluna "Área dos estabelecimentos" for igual a um nº, a média se dará pela divisão da coluna "Área dos estabelecimentos" por coluna "Nº dos estabelecimentos"

Comment: Quando se têm um número na coluna área, esta somando área e nº de estabelecimentos e dividindo por 2, assim como quando é X e soma-se Minimo e máximo e divide por 2, mas no caso em que se tem um número apenas é necessário a divisão da coluna Área pela Coluna nº de estabelecimentos

Comment: @IngledMCardoso Tem razão, desculpe, não tinha percebido. Agora está `area.est/num.est`.